# Added Big Reactors to Skyfactory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After a few days of playing a Skyfactory map and setting up shop, I decided that I would add Big Reactors (and other mods) to my Skyfactory. The adding of the mods went perfectly, but when I look up what the recipe is for yellorium dust (should be from the sieve) I can only get it through yellorium ore, which I can't get at all.

My question after all that is:

How do I update the sieve output to include yellorium dust?

Comment: I do not have access to a mod pack that does this to get the config changes you would need. But all those packs use MineTweaker to add/alter/remove recipes. One of which is going to be for getting Yellorium dust from sifting. It would not be in there by default. If no one has looked this up by the time I get home Ill put in a full answer, but that will be 8ish hours from now. Hope this comment atleast gets people started in the right direction (ie: download Agrarian Skies and find the minetweaker config files to see the syntax to add it in).

Comment: I managed to find the config line needed to do what I want in Skyblock.cfg:
mods.exnihilo.sieve.addRecipe(Sand, YelloriumDust, 64);

I can't get it to work since I have nearly no knowledge on how MineTweaker works :(

Comment: @James Did you manage to find what I should be doing to make Skyfactory recognise my edit?

Answer (score 3):

in the modtweaker config you need to add the line

```
mods.exnihilo.Sieve.addRecipe(<minecraft:Sand>, <BigReactors:YelloriumDust>, 64);
```

you may need to change `<BigReactors:YelloriumDust>` to match the correct item ID.

if you are in 1.6.4 then you need to use the numeric IDs instead which you'll find in NEI.

Comment: The point is I didn't have a single .cfg in the folder where they should be. I have no clue on how to make MineTweaker recognise that I've added a .cfg to the folder

Answer (score -2):

I dont think you can, becouse the map is already loaded

but if u have worldedit u could do: //replacenear RADIUS 1 499%1,1%ITEM-ID

that means in a radius of RADIUS all stone is replaced with 499%stone and 1%ITEM-ID

so 1block every 500blocks is ITEM-ID

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what James commented is possible. I just need to figure out how to make MineTweaker recognise my edit. This is a more "cheaty" way of obtaining Yellorium. I also know that I don't have any stone anyway since Skyfactory starts you on top of a tree with a single dirt block under it. I can't really rely (is that how you spell it?) on world gen to help me out here.

Comment: i thought it was a big world so this way u still had to search for the item